# Difference between equirectangular and other panoramas

Tags: image-processing, projection, panoramas

What is the difference between an equirectangular panorama, and a normal panorama? If there is a difference, how does one go about converting any panorama into its equirectangular equivalent?

Algorithms and mathematical descriptions, or links to such resources would be appreciated.

Comment: An equirectangular panorama essentially takes a spherical environment and maps it onto a flat plane.  The width/height ratio is usually 2:1 where the horizontal axis denotes the azimuthal sweep while the vertical denotes the latitudinal sweep.  A normal panorama is only an azimuthal sweep and doesn't take latitude into account.  You also can't convert any panorama into equirectangular because not all of them capture everything in 360 degrees and so there is missing information.  If you actually explain what exactly you want to do with this, I'd be more inclined to help you.

Comment: I am actually aiming to achieve the "Little Planet" effect, @rayreng.